# How to enable tabs in Windows Explorer (W11)

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, tabs

I have an up-to-date Windows 11 system installed on my computer. (According to Windows Update, and no optional updates available.)

However, I don't have the tab feature in Windows Explorer.

- **How can I enable it?**

Here's my System info:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎2022-‎01-‎22
OS build    22000.2245
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22001.1000.0
```

Comment: 21H2 is not the latest Windows update, mine (with the tabs) is 22H2 Build 22621.1992

Comment: It seems so, but Windows offers me no upgrade option. It does state that it is up to date.)

Comment: https://www.ubackup.com/windows-11/windows-11-22h2-update-not-showing.html

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if 22H2 is NOT showing up in Windows Update, then you either have a group policy that is blocking the update or potentially there is a hardware block on your hardware.  However, at this point 21H2, is actually nearing it's own end of life since 21H2 is only supported for 18 months (October 2023).  I mention this EOL date, because the most likely explanation, is an Administrator has specifically blocked 22H2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tabs you need to have Windows 11 22H2 that is fully updated.

If the 22H2 update does not appear in Windows Update,
you can force it by doing
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

This operation is equivalent to doing a major Windows upgrade,
so you should take similar precautions.